# Why is RC4 not able to handle large amount of encrypted data?

Tags: java, security, encryption, bouncycastle, jce

I have following code that decrypts a file.

```
package encryption;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Decrypter {

    private static final String PASSWORD = "t_9Y#i@eT[h3}-7!";
    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "RC4"; //Using Salsa20 or HC256 solves the problem
    private static final String PROVIDER = "BC";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
        File outputFile = new File(args[1]);

        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray()));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);

        byte []byteBuffer = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()]; 
        cipherInputStream.read(byteBuffer);
        outputStream.write(byteBuffer); //Only 512bytes of decrypted data is written to file, the rest becomes null
        outputStream.close();
    }

}
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't RC4 decrypt a block of size more than 512 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael Lowman has the correct answer, but I'd thought I'd show another way just to advertise a feature of the DataInputStream class.

You can the read-it-all-in-one-go behavior, like a perl slurp, by using the `DataInputStream.readFully()` method. In your example, you can read in the bytes with this method, then write them out and decrypt by using as CipherOutputStream instead of a CipherInputStream.

Consider the following fragment as an example:

```
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    dis.readFully(byteBuffer);
    dis.close();
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);
    cos.write(byteBuffer);
    cos.close();
```

Comment: The program is supposed to decrypt data. Writing through a CipherOutStream will encrypt it. And secondly, DataInputStream is used to read Java primitives, like integers or chars. So I don't see your point. Why would reading raw bytes not work?

Comment: @Monika Michael: The CipherOutputStream will transform the data according to how the it's Cipher parameter is initialized. In this case it is initialized in decrypt mode, so it does decryption. DataInputStream is not *supposed* to do any more or less than what its methods are defined to do. And the `readFully()` method has the semantics you have been looking for and erroneously claiming exist in `FileInputStream.read()`.

Comment: Thank you GregS, now I do think that the problem was with InputStream. Unlike FileInputStream that reads data equal to the length of buffer provided to it, CipherInputStream just reads one block of data. The default block size for RC4 is 512bytes which is what I was getting.

Comment: Coming late I know, but how could this be tailored to cater for huge files (files that cannot be fully loaded in memory) ? What should the pattern for the loop be?

Comment: @mariosk89: You would just use the fairly standard I/O loop where you have a small buffer of size e.g. 8192, fill it from the InputStream and write it to the outputstream.

Answer (score 8):

RC4 is a stream cipher, so it can decode any amount of data. Your issue is that InputStreams are not read in massive chunks. Normally you loop around the read call until there is no more data left to read and use a small buffer. See the [documentation of read()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])).

This could be implemented as

```
while(true) {
    int numRead = cipherInputStream.read(byteBuffer);
    if(numRead == -1)
        break;
    outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, numRead);
}
```

Comment: So true. Never never ever discard the return value of `read()`.

Comment: if the problem is with the InputStream why does changing the cipher algorithm solve the problem. Try running the code with salsa20 it runs just fine.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with cipher block mode. Still reading up on that...

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream.read` only returns a certain amount of data, you are supposed to loop until the stream is empty. However I suggest you use commons-io's `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream, File)` to copy the streams rather than rolling your own...

Comment: i don't think that is the problem. Could you point to any Oracle documentation that says FileInputStream will read an arbitrary amount of data? It is a blocking stream. i.e. the read method call will not return until the required amount of data has been read, which in this case happens to be the size of of the entire file.

Comment: @Monika Michael: The javadocs don't say that. They say the method blocks until *some* data is available. And in any event, you are reading from a CipherInputStream, not a FileInputStream.

Comment: @GregS CipherInputStream is linked to FileInputStream. :-) And that blocking until data becomes available holds true only when reading data over a network, not from the disk.

Comment: @MonikaMichael: *And that blocking until data becomes available holds true only when reading data over a network, not from the disk*. This is simply false.